# Routes and Path in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

i am currently dvelpping a website for a friend and i have a strange issue.
Let me first say i am rather a non experienced developper and I cant seem to find a solution:
I've localized my websites in different languages you can watch it here:
http://parfum-poudre.fr/en (in English) it works fine
but if you go to http://parfum-poudre.fr/en/ the paths are messed up and some pics don't appear...
for example there is a professional sapce on this website but then if you go back on the public space i have the same issue...
anyone ha s anything to say about that ?

Thanks

Comment: What does your route.php look like?

Answer (score 1):

Have added your images, scripts and styles using normal HTML tag in layout file?
This can be one issue.
You can add images,scripts and styles to your layout file using

```
<?php
echo $this -> Html -> css('style');
echo $this -> Html -> script('jquery');

echo $this -> fetch('css');
echo $this -> fetch('script');


?>
<?php echo $this->Html->image('logo2.png', array('url' => '/ProjectName/','alt'=>'Logo')); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll look into that right now and let you know asap

Comment: Hi gvLearner I've tried your solution it seems to work but my website as many callback in javascript and i think all the links should be re work properly so for now i'm looking another way to solve this.. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `app_helper.php`

```
class AppHelper extends Helper {
    function url($url = null, $full = false) {
        $routerUrl = Router::url($url, $full);
        if (!preg_match('/\\.(rss|html|js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|xml?)$/', strtolower($routerUrl)) && substr($routerUrl, -1) != '/') {
            $routerUrl .= '/';
        }
        return $routerUrl;
    }
}
```

The AppHelper stuff goes in the app_helper.php file located in `HTDOCS/PROJECT/APP` folder (APP ROOT). If the file doesn't exits, create one.

And edit your .htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

The .htaccess code goes in the .htaccess file in `HTDOCS/PROJECT/APP/WEBROOT` folder (APP ROOT/WEBROOT). Just replace the original contents and make sure you change domain.com to whatever your domain is.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I've thought I could do this with Htaccess tweaking but i was completely lost I'll try this right away

Comment: Hi Jack I've tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work. I'm still investigating to solve this issue.. Thanks for your help

Comment: Btw Jack I'm not familiar (yet!!) with stackoverflow and I just saw your question about my routes.php... Maybe you could help me because I xas thinking about setting up routes for /fr and /fr/ but I'm really lost. Here is my `Routes.php` code:`Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index')); Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')); Router::connect('/pro', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 42));`